# comparing the record with the database record whether exists or not

Tags: android, sqlite

I wrote the below code for compare the record with the database record.its comparing but inserting all the records

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
  if(v.equals(add))
  {
     if(ifExisting())
       {
        insert();
     Log.e("Data Inserting","true");
     Intent i=new Intent(AddCategory.this,ShareFolioActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
        //Toast.makeText(AddCategory.this, "Already exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

   else
         {
              Toast.makeText(AddCategory.this, "Already exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Log.e("Data Inserting","false");
      }
  }

    }

boolean ifExisting() {

     Log.e("wquery","SELECT * FROM  sharelist  WHERE category='"+category.getText().toString()+"'");
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT category FROM  sharelist  WHERE category='"+category.getText().toString()+";'",null);



     if(c.getCount()==-1)
      {

       Log.e("Condition true","true");
       return false;
      } 

      else
      {
       Log.e("Condition true","false");
          return true;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `if(ifExisting())
       {
        insert();`

shouldn't it instead be `if(!ifExisting())
       {
        insert();`

Otherwise you are inserting if it exists.

Comment: now any record is not entering (i.e;showing "Already exists")

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be expecting that `c.getCount()` will be -1 if the query returns 0 rows. Why wouldn't it return 0? (I don't remember seeing a case where it returns -1, but perhaps my memory is faulty.)

In any case, checking for `c.getCount() <= 0` would seem to be safer.

Also, this query

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT category FROM  sharelist  WHERE category='"+category.getText().toString()+";'",null);
```

is malformed -- look at the end where you have `";'"`. You want to have `"'"` there. (Query strings that are passed to `rawQuery` must not end in a semicolon; otherwise, `"';"` would be the correct choice.)

As others have said to you on other threads, you really don't want to be making queries by concatenation; using the selectionArgs argument is a much safer way to pass query values.